# executing Desktop.getDesktop().open(FILE) throws error

Tags: java, file, video, vlc

I'm trying to open a local video in Java, but when is executed

```
Desktop.getDesktop().open(FILE)
```

the video is opening but afterwards I can see this output in the shell

```
[0000000000b07148] core libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
[00007fe7b0c01808] avi demux error: no key frame set for track 1
[00007fe7980009c8] vdpau_avcodec generic error: unsupported codec 13 or profile -1
Failed to open VDPAU backend libvdpau_va_gl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
QObject::~QObject: Timers cannot be stopped from another thread
```

and even if I close the video the program doesn't regain the control, the shell remains blocked and the only thing I can do is press ctrl+C.
I'm using linux Mint and the default video program is vlc.
What can I do?

EDIT: I notice that the same errors are displayed even if I execute

```
vlc path_to_file
```

from shell

Comment: those all look like errors from vlc, not from java, thus your problem doesn't lie in the Desktop#open() call